# Multiple coins chance of getting all coins to land on both sides

Tags: probability

I have $n$ coins. After $x$ tosses, there's an above 85% chance all coins have landed on both sides. What is $x$?

I've done it for one coin by using $0.85<1-(1/2)^x$ which gets 3 throws but don't know how to add the multiple coins into it

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I've done it for one coin by using 0.85<1-(1/2)^n which gets 3 throws but don't know how to add the multiple coins into it

Answer (score 1):

Your solution for a single coin is not quite correct.  For $x=1$ it gives a chance of $\frac 12$, but it can't land on both sides the first time.  You should start counting after the first throw as you are looking for it to fall on the other side, so the chance it has fallen on both sides after $x$ throws is $1-(\frac 12)^{x-1}$.  When you want $n$ coins all to succeed, you multiply the probabilities, so you need $0.85 \lt \left(1-(\frac 12)^{x-1}\right)^n$